# Will I get into trouble if I included some real life historical characters in my historical fiction / alternate history novel?

Tags: creative-writing, historical-fiction, alternative-history

I'm planning on writing a story set in the past with some historical events as the background. My story will involve the protagonist meeting with some real life characters in history (a fictional narrative of course).

Will I get into trouble if I directly included these characters in my story line? Will there be any legal repercussions?

Comment: Are the people in question living or dead as of 2019?

Comment: You can find good answers to this question in @Cyn's link there.

Comment: Yes, that link helps. I gather that there' no issues on using historical characters in fiction as long as their said reputation remains intact. @F1Krazy, nope the characters I am talking about are long dead.

Comment: No offence, but why are you pinging me after 18 months just to repeat something that you already told me?